# Get Matplotlib plot to show in front of browser when using Jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

When plotting in Classic Jupyter using Matplotlib the window typically shows up behind the browser (I'm in `qt` mode). Is there a way to programmatically force the figure to pop up in front of the browser window?

I have tried adding `plt.show()` but this doesn't do it.

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], [5,6,6])
plt.show()
```

I am sick of having to do extra keystrokes/clicks to bring it to the front (I am in Windows/Firefox if that matters).

Note as mentioned I am doing all this in qt mode (after entering `%matplotlib qt` in a cell), and doing the analysis in inline mode isn't really an option for this project.

Comment: See [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/100287/how-bring-to-front-on-windows): "An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user."

Comment: Have you seen [sidecar](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar) or [stickyland](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/stickyland-break-the-linear-presentation-of-jupyter-notebooks-with-sticky-cells/13275?u=fomightez)?